# SCSS include? for a list

Tags: sass

I want to be able to compare an item against a list, to see if the current item exists in the list, like so:

```scss
$elements: one two three four five;
$picked: two five;

@for $i from 1 through length($elements) {
  @if not index($picked, nth($elements, $i)) == false {
  }
}
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I should RTFM more often. There's the `index()` function that returns false if it doesn't exists in the list